# NetWorkCredentials not showing up in headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have two projects: a Web API project and a client project.

In the client application, I configure my `HttpClient` like this.

```
services.AddHttpClient<TrackAndTraceClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Username, settings.Password),
        };
    });
```

And then in my class that calls the API:

```
public TrackAndTraceClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IOptions<TrackAndTraceSettings> settings)
{
    HttpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(TrackAndTraceClient));
    Settings = settings.Value;
}
```

My Web API site implements basic authentication using the techniques described in [this article](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-basic-authentication-to-asp-net-core-application). But my code throws an exception because no *Authorization* header is found.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {

        // ...

        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out StringValues authHeaderValues))
            throw new Exception("Missing Authorization header");

        // ...
    }
}
```

I can only get this to work by adding the following code to my class that calls the API:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
byte[] credentialsData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{Settings.Username}:{Settings.Password}");
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialsData);
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}");
```

Can anyone tell me why this last block of code is needed? Why doesn't setting the credentials with `NetworkCredential` appear to do anything? And how can I change my Web API so that it works with credentials specified the original way?

Note that I'm also calling a third-party API, and the client is configured exactly the same way as in my first block of code. So I know that can be made to work.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the actual HTTP requests and responses to the third party system and your server. Does your WebAPI return HTTP 401 Unauthorized with WWW-Authenticate: Basic header, for example? I wouldn't expect the HttpClientHandler to engage in authorization process unless instructed.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek: I'm checking the header in my basic authentication handler (see [this article](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-basic-authentication-to-asp-net-core-application)). So the Web API returns whatever I indicate.

Comment: I'm going by memory here, so bear with me. You're creating a typed `HttpClient` (`.AddHttpClient<>()`), not a named `HttpClient` (`.AddHttpClient(string)`)... so when you inject `IHttpClientFactory` and run `.CreateClient(string)` it won't find a client with your setup. Using a typed client you shouldn't need to use `IHttpClientFactory` at all, but just inject a `HttpClient` directly.

Comment: @GTHvidsten: Yes, it looks like you might be right about not needing `IHttpClientFactory` with dependency injection. I'm currently reviewing that. However, my code still gets an instance of `HttpClient` that is configured by my code aside from the authorization headers. So this suggestion doesn't appear related to the issue I'm having.

Comment: @GTHvidsten: Actually, I tried changing my class to just receive an instance of `HttpClient` instead of `IHttpClientFactory`. However, `BaseAddress` is now null. So I don't fully understand how this works but the instance I'm getting now is no longer initialized.

Comment: @JonathanWood Can you include the actual code you have in your `BasicAuthenticationHandler` please? The issue is reproducible when the code lacks `Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");`

Comment: @pfx: Well, I am showing the part of the code that fails. And it's right at the start of my `BasicAuthenticationHandler` class, so I don't think it matters what came after that. What else would be helpful?

Comment: @JonathanWood It is the before part that I'm interested in: you do have the part:
`Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");`?

Comment: @pfx: The code that fails is in my Web API application. Obviously, that application never sets any headers. It only reads them. The credentials must be set in my client application. But the failing code is in the Web API application.

Comment: @JonathanWood That's not completely true; that `BasicAuthenticationHandler`  must set the `WWW-Authenticate` header - as shown in the article.

That is the header upon which the `HttpClient` reacts to include the `Authorization` `HTTP` header when it receives a `401` `Unauthorized` response.

Comment: @pfx: OMG! You are right! I'm a little confused as I thought the 401 response was triggered by my code returning `AuthenticateResult.Fail("Access Denied")`. But in fact, adding that response header, now it works. I don't quite understand but you have appeared to crack the issue. Feel free to write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our conversation in the comments section -

The implementation of your `BasicAuthenticationHandler` lacks adding the `WWW-Authenticate` `HTTP` header (with value `Basic`).

That is the header upon which the `HttpClient` reacts to include the `Authorization` `HTTP` header when it receives a `401` `Unauthorized` response.

To resolve the issue, add the line below to the `BasicAuthenticationHandler`.

```
Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
```

Now the `NetworkCredentials` will go into the `Authorization` `HTTP` header.

---

In short without being complete about how this works;
when a `HttpClient` makes a request (without `Authorization` header), and receives a `401 Unauthorized` response in combination with a `WWW-Authenticate` `HTTP` header, it will make a 2nd attempt with the configured credentials - if any - in the `Authorization` `HTTP` header.

---

For simplicity, you might want to include the `Authorization` at once, without relying on `NetworkCredentials` and `WWW-Authenticate` `HTTP` headers.

```
services.AddHttpClient<TrackAndTraceClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        // Add below to your existing code.
        var digest = Convert.ToBase64String(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{settings.Username}:{settings.Password}")
            );  
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {digest}");
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you know how the handler in [this article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/21/aspnet-core-3-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) works? I don't see where it sets the *WWW-Authenticate* header.

Comment: Is it correct to say it's less efficient to set the credentials using `NetworkCredential` because then it requires two requests (one to get the 401, and the second with the headers set)? And that setting the headers directly would be more efficient, saving one of the requests?

Comment: About efficiency yes; that's why most code examples set the `Authorization` `HTTP` header themselves - remember my first/deleted answer ;)

Comment: Yes, okay. Knowing this, I may implement the code from your first answer. But I wanted an explanation for why it was needed. It's coming together for me. Thanks. Stackoverflow won't let me accept an answer yet.

Comment: @JonathanWood I included that part back in this answer here, just to make it more complete for future reference or so.

Comment: Yes, I was almost going to suggest that (even though I'm doing something similar in my question).

Comment: I can also see that using this same technique with the third-party API I'm calling does not work. The reason must be that it doesn't use basic authentication. So the advantage of using `NetworkCredential` is that `HttpClient` will negotiate the authentication for you. But you can do it faster if you know ahead what type of authentication is used.